# Show toolbar when tinymce react has focus and hide the toolbar when focus is out

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to Show the toolbar only when tinymce editor has focus and hide the toolbar as soon as editor lost the focus. I'm using classic toolbar with default floating toolbar_mode (I can change this if needed to achieve above requirement)
[image]